# Oracle SQL Pivot query additional column from same table

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

As I'm new to the PIVOT function, I have a hard time with the following query:

**Sample data:**

```
Name  |  Tab | Attribute | Value
====================================
Set1  |  A   |  Street   | Wall St.
Set1  |  A   |  ZIP      | 12345
Set1  |  B   |  Street   | Route 66
Set1  |  B   |  No       | 7
Set1  |  C   |  Street   | (null)
Set2  |  A   |  Street   | Oxford St
Set2  |  A   |  ZIP      | (null)
Set2  |  B   |  No       | (null)
```

**Expected result:**

```
Name  | Street_from_Tab_A  |  ZIP  | No
=========================================
Set1  | Wall St.           | 12345 | 7
Set2  | Oxford St          | (null)| (null)
```

What I tried so far:

```
select name, street_from_tab_a, zip, no from my_table
PIVOT (max(value) for attribute in ('Street' as street_from_tab_a, 'ZIP' as ZIP, 'No' as No)) 
where tab = 'A';
```

How can I add "No" from Tab "B" as column?

Comment: And why don't you want ZIP for both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to pivot on the combination of Tab and Attribute:

```
SELECT name, street_from_tab_a, zip, no
  FROM My_Table
 PIVOT (max(value)
   FOR (tab, attribute) in (('A','Street') street_from_tab_a
                           ,('A','ZIP') zip
                           ,('B','No') no)) pvt
```

Comment: Exactly! Thank you very much!